# Proving the generating functions version of Newton's identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, generating-functions, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

We are asked to prove the identity in the generating functions version in the **Expressing elementary symmetric polynomials in terms of power sums** section of [the Wikipedia page on Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums)

The following is what I am thinking about now:

I have not even seen generating functions before, and since $\infty$ is not a number, I do not know that if it suffices to prove that for any $n$ in **N** every coefficient of $T^n$ consists. If so, I think maybe it can be done using induction.

I have not familiar with the exponential generating functions so I am afraid that there are some useful properties of this function which I do not know. If so, could someone tell me what property of this function should I use?

Seeing this question:[Using generating functions find the sum $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 +\dotsb+ n^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209268/using-generating-functions-find-the-sum-13-23-33-dotsb-n3) 
I guess maybe there is an algorithm to translate a given recurrence into generating functions.

But until now I have not found a track to prove it, Could someone please prove it or give some hints? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The proofs in the link

https://holdenlee.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/newton-sums/ and

https://yakovenko.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/lecture5symmetry.pdf

are understandable and in generating functions version.

But they are not in exponential generating functions version. I do know that there is a method to translate ordinary generating functions into exponential version. But I cannot understand the principle behind the method and I am afraid that I cannot use that. So is it possible to modify the proofs above to give the desired conclusion? Any hint will be appreciate? Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2100857/155436

Comment: @CountIblis Sorry I have no back groud of exponential generating function as well as log generating function. May I ask what should I learn about from this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you  need here is the  following statement: the OGF  of the cycle
index $Z(P_k)$  of the  unlabeled set operator  $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}_{=k}$ is
given by

$$Z(P_k) = [w^k]
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} a_l \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

This  is known as  the exponential  formula.  To  see this  consider a
repertoire of variables $\sum_q  X_q$ and substitute the corresponding
power sum

$$a_l = \sum_q X_q^l$$

into the formula to get

$$Z(P_k)\left(\sum X_q\right)
= [w^k]
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} \sum_q X_q^l \frac{w^l}{l}\right)
\\ = [w^k] \prod_q
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} X_q^l \frac{w^l}{l}\right)\\
\\ = [w^k] \prod_q \exp\log(1 + w X_q)
= [w^k] \prod_q (1 + w X_q)$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{Q\subseteq X, |Q|=k} \prod_{X_q\in Q} X_q}$$

by  inspection and  we have  expressed the  elementary  polynomials in
terms of power sums.

**Readings.** A closely related identity was discussed at this [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242641/)  and the proof
was          given         at          this          [MSE         link
II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560601/).   An  alternate
proof due to Lovasz is included among the links at [Wikipedia on cycle
indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index).

**Example.**   The   cycle   index   $Z(P_6)$  for   the   operator
$\textsc{SET}_{=6}$ is given by

$$Z(P_6) = {\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{6}}{720}}-1/48\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{4}
\\+1/18\,a_{{3}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}
-1/8\,a_{{4}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}-1/6\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}
\\+1/5\,a_{{5}}a_{{1}}-1/48\,{a_{{2}}}^{3}
+1/8\,a_{{2}}a_{{4}}+1/18\,{a_{{3}}}^{2}-1/6\,a_{{6}}.$$

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But your answer is far more beyond my knowledge. I have posted another question which is more specific (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161737/prove-the-identity-between-formal-power-series-in-t). Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks like it has been closed. I for one understood your question immediately on seeing the Wikipedia entry.